# how to convert to lower case in c++ using files

Tags: c++

I need to convert each word to lower case in file by looping on all file's sentences. I would like to use cout each word after I convert it. I assume I need to use c_str() some how.

Comment: Using what encoding and alphabets? Note that to do this properly, you'll want a high-quality Unicode text processing library, C++ does not support this out-of-the-box. If you're only concerned with ASCII code-points in `char`-typed values then that's a lot simpler.

Comment: Do you have to loop on sentences? Can you loop on lines?

Comment: `std::transform` and `std::tolower` may be of use for you. No need for `std::string::c_str`.

Comment: @user4581301 `std::tolower` is inappropriate for modern text processing because its behavior is undefined for values that don't fit in `unsigned char`.

Comment: Good point. It's 2018 and my head is still stuck in ASCII.

Comment: This sounds like two questions:  How to convert text to lower case and how to do file i/o?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you didn't try writing the code yourself, but here's how:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
  int dummycount=1,count=1;
  char next_char;
  ifstream input_file;

  input_file.open("<file-name>");

  if (input_file.fail()){
    cout << "Could not open file\n";
    exit(0);
  }

  while (!input_file.eof()){
    input_file.get(next_char);
    if(isspace(next_char)){
      count++;
      dummycount++;
    }else{
      if (dummycount>0){
        cout << " ";
      }
      dummycount=0;
      cout << static_cast<char> (tolower(next_char));
   }
 }
 input_file.close();
 cout << "Total words:" << count<< endl;
}
```